# Converting Date String (31-Jan) to date (MM/DD)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have an AD property that contains birthdays in the format of DD-MMM (31-Jan). I need to query this via powershell and return it as 01/31. I have attempted ParseExact, 31-Jan is not recognized as a valid date format.

Thanks in advance for any help I am a powershell novice. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use Parse.

Example:

```
[DateTime]::Parse("31-jan").ToString("MM/dd")
```

I would think this should get you unblocked.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
"{0:MM/dd}" -f (Get-Date 31-Jan)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
Get-Date '31-Jan' -f 'MM/dd'
```